# Adding indexes slows down my query in PostgreSQL but the opposite is true in SQLite

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, query-optimization

I have the following table in my PostgreSQL database (v13.8, running on Debian 11 (Bullseye)) which contains ~15,000,000 rows:

```
=> \d ncbitaxon
               Table "public.ncbitaxon"
   Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 assertion  | integer |           |          | 
 retraction | integer |           |          | 0
 graph      | text    |           |          | 
 subject    | text    |           |          | 
 predicate  | text    |           |          | 
 object     | text    |           |          | 
 datatype   | text    |           |          | 
 annotation | text    |           |          |
```

The table does not have a primary key and is such that each `subject` field can be associated with multiple `object` and `predicate` fields. I would like to retrieve every subject that is associated with the `predicate` 'rdf:type' and the `object` 'owl:Class', but that is *not* associated with the `predicate` 'rdfs:subClassOf'.

The table has no indexes, and when I run the following query I get an answer back consistently in under 2s (which I consider acceptable):

```
select n1.subject
  from ncbitaxon n1
 where n1.predicate = 'rdf:type'
   and n1.object = 'owl:Class'
   and not exists (
     select 1
       from ncbitaxon n2
      where n2.subject = n1.subject
        and n2.predicate = 'rdfs:subClassOf'
   )
```

However when I add (non-unique) btree indexes on each of the `subject`, `object`, `predicate`, and `datatype` columns the performance slows down considerably, so that my result comes back consistently in about 9s or so (which is too slow).

I realise that indexes are not a silver bullet and can (evidently) sometimes even slow down select queries.

But what puzzles me is that when I run the same query on the same table, but this time in SQLite (v3.34.1, running on the same laptop), I have the opposite effect. I.e., with those indexes I get a result in about 5s, and without the indexes I eventually have to press Ctrl-C because I get fed up of waiting for the result to come back.

I wondered if this might be due to some sort of caching effect, so I tried clearing PostgreSQL's cache by running:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
systemctl restart postgresql
```

And indeed there is a bit of a cache effect, because the first time I run the query in PostgreSQL after doing this it takes about 3s (instead of 2s). But this is still faster than running the query in either SQLite (~5s) or PostgreSQL (~9s) if I have those indexes in place.

I'm confused. Anyone know what's going on here?

The create index statements are:

```
create index idx_77907_idx_ncbitaxon_predicate on ncbitaxon (predicate);
create index idx_77907_idx_ncbitaxon_subject on ncbitaxon (subject);
create index idx_77907_idx_ncbitaxon_object on ncbitaxon (object);
create index idx_77907_idx_ncbitaxon_datatype on ncbitaxon (datatype);
```

Here is the output of `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` for the with-indexes case:

```
                                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                                            
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.56..549629.43 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=5354.149..7223.752 rows=2 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   Buffers: shared hit=12556526 read=226206
   ->  Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=0.56..548629.33 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=5942.986..7184.393 rows=1 loops=3)
         Buffers: shared hit=12556526 read=226206
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ncbitaxon n1  (cost=0.00..295443.22 rows=168032 width=17) (actual time=137.371..630.607 rows=812952 loops=3)
               Filter: ((predicate = 'rdf:type'::text) AND (object = 'owl:Class'::text))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 4250687
               Buffers: shared hit=6214 read=194286
         ->  Index Scan using idx_77907_idx_ncbitaxon_subject on ncbitaxon n2  (cost=0.56..3.46 rows=5 width=17) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=1 loops=2438855)
               Index Cond: (subject = n1.subject)
               Filter: (predicate = 'rdfs:subClassOf'::text)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 4
               Buffers: shared hit=12550312 read=31920
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=14 read=6
 Planning Time: 1.054 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 27
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 6.551 ms, Inlining 111.762 ms, Optimization 182.297 ms, Emission 117.506 ms, Total 418.115 ms
 Execution Time: 7228.950 ms
(23 rows)
```

and here it is for the no-indexes case:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=299030.49..603580.05 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=1461.791..1500.212 rows=2 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   Buffers: shared hit=25757 read=375369, temp read=22444 written=22996
   ->  Parallel Hash Anti Join  (cost=298030.49..602579.95 rows=1 width=17) (actual time=1425.751..1432.604 rows=1 loops=3)
         Hash Cond: (n1.subject = n2.subject)
         Buffers: shared hit=25757 read=375369, temp read=22444 written=22996
         ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ncbitaxon n1  (cost=0.00..295443.22 rows=168032 width=17) (actual time=0.021..447.123 rows=812952 loops=3)
               Filter: ((predicate = 'rdf:type'::text) AND (object = 'owl:Class'::text))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 4250687
               Buffers: shared hit=12868 read=187632
         ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=279619.35..279619.35 rows=1002811 width=17) (actual time=694.169..694.170 rows=812951 loops=3)
               Buckets: 65536  Batches: 64  Memory Usage: 2624kB
               Buffers: shared hit=12772 read=187728, temp written=11456
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ncbitaxon n2  (cost=0.00..279619.35 rows=1002811 width=17) (actual time=139.958..552.807 rows=812951 loops=3)
                     Filter: (predicate = 'rdfs:subClassOf'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 4250687
                     Buffers: shared hit=12772 read=187728
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=5 dirtied=1
 Planning Time: 0.582 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 39
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 6.349 ms, Inlining 93.709 ms, Optimization 198.947 ms, Emission 126.610 ms, Total 425.615 ms
 Execution Time: 1504.890 ms
(26 rows)
```

The output of `explain` in SQLite (with indexes) is:

```
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     27    0                    0   Start at 27  
1     OpenRead       0     34019  0     6              0   root=34019 iDb=0; ncbitaxon
2     OpenRead       2     519613  0     k(2,,)         2   root=519613 iDb=0; idx_ncbitaxon_object
3     String8        0     1     0     owl:Class      0   r[1]='owl:Class'
4     SeekGE         2     26    1     1              0   key=r[1]     
5       IdxGT          2     26    1     1              0   key=r[1]     
6       DeferredSeek   2     0     0                    0   Move 0 to 2.rowid if needed
7       Column         0     4     2                    0   r[2]=ncbitaxon.predicate
8       Ne             3     25    2     BINARY-8       82  if r[2]!=r[3] goto 25
9       Integer        0     4     0                    0   r[4]=0; Init EXISTS result
10      Integer        1     5     0                    0   r[5]=1; LIMIT counter
11      OpenRead       1     34019  0     5              0   root=34019 iDb=0; ncbitaxon
12      OpenRead       3     332263  0     k(2,,)         2   root=332263 iDb=0; idx_ncbitaxon_subject
13      Column         0     3     6                    0   r[6]=ncbitaxon.subject
14      SeekGE         3     22    6     1              0   key=r[6]     
15        IdxGT          3     22    6     1              0   key=r[6]     
16        DeferredSeek   3     0     1                    0   Move 1 to 3.rowid if needed
17        Column         1     4     7                    0   r[7]=ncbitaxon.predicate
18        Ne             8     21    7     BINARY-8       82  if r[7]!=r[8] goto 21
19        Integer        1     4     0                    0   r[4]=1       
20        DecrJumpZero   5     22    0                    0   if (--r[5])==0 goto 22
21      Next           3     15    1                    0                
22      If             4     25    1                    0                
23      Column         0     3     10                   0   r[10]=ncbitaxon.subject
24      ResultRow      10    1     0                    0   output=r[10] 
25    Next           2     5     1                    0                
26    Halt           0     0     0                    0                
27    Transaction    0     0     77    0              1   usesStmtJournal=0
28    String8        0     3     0     rdf:type       0   r[3]='rdf:type'
29    String8        0     8     0     rdfs:subClassOf  0   r[8]='rdfs:subClassOf'
30    Goto           0     1     0                    0
```

Finally, here is the output of `explain query plan` in SQLite:

```
QUERY PLAN
|--SEARCH TABLE ncbitaxon AS n1 USING INDEX idx_ncbitaxon_object (object=?)
`--CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
   `--SEARCH TABLE ncbitaxon AS n2 USING INDEX idx_ncbitaxon_subject (subject=?)
```

Comment: Did you try a single index on the combination of object, subject and predicate ? (maybe in a different order, just try, it depends on the data)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes I already tried this.

Comment: The index idx_77907_idx_ncbitaxon_subject is useless, when using this one, the database still has to filter for predicate, see the query plan. What happens when you make an index on the combination of the two? (and please share the query plan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot give a complete answer, but here are some ideas:

- In the slow plan, PostgreSQL underestimates the number of rows found in `ncbitaxon n1` by a factor of almost 5. Try to improve that estimate, either by running `ANALYZE` to collect fresh statistics, or, if that is not sufficient, by creating extended statistics for the correlation of these columns.

  If that estimate is more accurate, the slow plan will be estimated with a higher cost and will not be chosen.
- In the slow plan, the repeated index scan on `ncbitaxon n2` is much more expensive than PostgreSQL estimates. This is partly due to the mis-estimate above, but perhaps `random_page_cost` is set lower than appropriate for your hardware, so that PostgreSQL underestimates the cost of an index scan.

Comment: Thanks this is interesting. I'll look into these suggestions.

Comment: Temporarily increasing the `random_page_cost` parameter works. When I set it high enough PostgreSQL correctly chooses the faster (in this case) sequential scan. I now need to do some more investigation into what the optimal value for my hardware is, since I can't remove those indexes entirely as they are needed for other queries on that table. Thanks again. That suggestion was very helpful.

Comment: Running `create statistics ncbitaxon_statistics on subject, predicate, object from ncbitaxon ; analyze ncbitaxon` also works just as well, and seems like a more desirable solution than changing the `random_page_cost`.

Comment: Yes, extended statistics is the better solution. I didn't mean to indiscriminately increase `random_page_cost`, just to set it to a value appropriate for your hardware.